# Multithreading with inline assembly and access to a c variable

Tags: c, multithreading, assembly, x86, brute-force

I'm using inline assembly to construct a set of passwords, which I will use to brute force against a given hash. I used this [website](http://www.insidepro.com/doc/003e.shtml) as a reference for the construction of the passwords.

This is working flawlessly in a singlethreaded environment. It produces an infinite amount of incrementing passwords.

As I have only basic knowledge of asm, I understand the idea. The gcc uses ATT, so I compile with `-masm=intel`

During the attempt to multithread the program, I realize that this approach might not work.
The following code uses 2 global C variables, and I **assume** that this might be the problem.

```
__asm__("pushad\n\t"
    "mov edi, offset plaintext\n\t" <---- global variable
    "mov ebx, offset charsetTable\n\t" <---- again
    "L1: movzx eax, byte ptr [edi]\n\t"
    "    movzx eax, byte ptr [charsetTable+eax]\n\t"
    "    cmp al, 0\n\t"
    "    je L2\n\t"
    "    mov [edi],al\n\t"
    "    jmp L3\n\t"
    "L2: xlat\n\t"
    "    mov [edi],al\n\t"
    "    inc edi\n\t"
    "    jmp L1\n\t"
    "L3: popad\n\t");
```

It produces a non deterministic result in the plaintext variable.

How can i create a workaround, that every thread accesses his own plaintext variable? (If this is the problem...).

I tried modifying this code, to use extended assembly, but I failed every time. Probably due to the fact that all tutorials use ATT syntax.

I would really appreciate any help, as I'm stuck for several hours now :(

**Edit**: Running the program with 2 threads, and printing the content of plaintext right after the asm instruction, produces:
`b`
`b`
`d`
`d`
`f`
`f`
...

**Edit2**:

```
pthread_create(&thread[i], NULL, crack, (void *) &args[i]))
[...]
void *crack(void *arg) {
struct threadArgs *param = arg;
struct crypt_data crypt; // storage for reentrant version of crypt(3)

char *tmpHash = NULL;

size_t len = strlen(param->methodAndSalt);
size_t cipherlen = strlen(param->cipher);

crypt.initialized = 0;

for(int i = 0; i <= LIMIT; i++) {
    // intel syntax      
    __asm__ ("pushad\n\t"
    //mov edi, offset %0\n\t"
    "mov edi, offset plaintext\n\t"
    "mov ebx, offset charsetTable\n\t"
    "L1: movzx eax, byte ptr [edi]\n\t"
    "    movzx eax, byte ptr [charsetTable+eax]\n\t"
    "    cmp al, 0\n\t"
    "    je L2\n\t"
    "    mov [edi],al\n\t"
    "    jmp L3\n\t"
    "L2: xlat\n\t"
    "    mov [edi],al\n\t"
    "    inc edi\n\t"
    "    jmp L1\n\t"
    "L3: popad\n\t");

    tmpHash = crypt_r(plaintext, param->methodAndSalt, &crypt);
    if(0 == memcmp(tmpHash+len, param->cipher, cipherlen)) {
        printf("success: %s\n", plaintext);
        break;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You'd need to lock access to your `plaintext` and `charsetTable` variables, if two or more threads could access them.  It's hard to tell from what you posted, whether that is really the issue.  Can you show us the threading code?

Comment: Your should really declare your `asm` as `volatile` as otherwise GCC might move it. Additionally you should have `memory` in the clobberlist. See [here](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html#ss5.3).

Comment: Try to avoid global variables. In that case the easy way would be using stack variables. An other, more complicated possibility is using thread local variables.

Comment: BTW, the asm code is slow. Specifically the `xlat` instruction (which might have bee the fastest way 20 years ago) should be avoided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're already using pthreads, another option is making the variables that are modified by several threads into per-thread variables (threadspecific data). See [`pthread_getspecific` OpenGroup manpage](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_getspecific.html). The way this works is like:

In the main thread (before you create other threads), do:

```
static pthread_key_y tsd_key;
(void)pthread_key_create(&tsd_key);    /* unlikely to fail; handle if you want */
```

and then within each thread, where you use the `plaintext` / `charsetTable` variables (or more such), do:

```
struct { char *plainText, char *charsetTable } *str =
    pthread_getspecific(tsd_key);

if (str == NULL) {
    str = malloc(2 * sizeof(char *));
    str.plainText = malloc(size_of_plaintext);
    str.charsetTable = malloc(size_of_charsetTable);
    initialize(str.plainText);          /* put the data for this thread in */
    initialize(str.charsetTable);       /* ditto */
    pthread_setspecific(tsd_key, str);
}
char *plaintext = str.plainText;
char *charsetTable = str.charsetTable;
```

Or create / use several keys, one per such variable; in that case, you don't get the `str` container / double indirection / additional `malloc`.

Intel assembly syntax with gcc inline asm is, hm, not great; in particular, specifying input/output operands is not easy. I think to get that to use the `pthread_getspecific` mechanism, you'd change your code to do:

```
__asm__("pushad\n\t"
    "push tsd_key\n\t"               <---- threadspecific data key (arg to call)
    "call pthread_getspecific\n\t"   <---- gets "str" as per above
    "add esp, 4\n\t"                 <---- get rid of the func argument
    "mov edi, [eax]\n\t"             <---- first ptr == "plainText"
    "mov ebx, [eax + 4]\n\t"         <---- 2nd ptr == "charsetTable"
    ...
```

That way, it becomes lock-free, at the expense of using more memory (one plaintext / charsetTable per thread), and the expense of an additional function call (to `pthread_getspecific()`). Also, if you do the above, make sure you `free()` each thread's specific data via `pthread_atexit()`, or else you'll leak.

If your function is fast to execute, then a lock is a much simpler solution because you don't need all the setup / cleanup overhead of threadspecific data; if the function is either slow or very frequently called, the lock would become a bottleneck though - in that case the memory / access overhead for TSD is justified. Your mileage may vary.

Comment: this looks promising. I'll definitely try it. Thanks for your great and detailed post. appreciate it!

Comment: I marked this as my solution, as this is a direct answer to my question, i got rid of the global variable. Speed measurements show, that it's even a little bit faster. Thanks again

Comment: yes, it might be faster, since it's a "no data shared" case (you replicate the variable(s) once per thread); higher memory footprint vs. better parallelism.

Answer (score 1):

Protect this function with mutex outside of inline Assembly block.

Comment: i thought about it. Now i tried it. It seems to be working. But i guess this means a major loss of speed. I have to lock the `plaintext` then copy the content, before releasing the lock, and actually hashing the plaintext. But seems like ther is no other choice. thanks :)